# Multiple objects doing the same animation in the BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, objects

So I have some collectables in BGE that bob up and down. But when I play the animation they ALL go to the exact same place that I animated it for the first time. How do you keyframe location without meaning that *EXACT* location and only the location on one axis or something?

Answer (score 0):

I usually parent the object to an empty and place the empty at the base location.

Comment: Thats a good idea but I am moving it to unity where this won't work. Is there a way of keyframing something locally instead of world space?

Comment: The tag [game-engine] is meant to be used for the blender game engine. I suggest to ask at unity support websites.